# Convert column to row matrix with the frequency of its values in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, matrix, transpose

I have a table that looks like this (using SAS SQL):

| id | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | blue |
| 1 | green |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | red |
| 2 | blue |

and I am trying to get it to look like this:

| id | red | blue | green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

To summarize, I am trying to transpose the column to row and then in the cells have the frequency that each category occurs per ID.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count. Then transpose.

```
proc freq data=have ;
  tables id*color / noprint out=counts;
run;
proc transpose data=counts out=want(drop=_name_ _label_);
  by id;
  id color;
  var count;
run;
```

You can get zeros instead of missing if you add the SPARSE option to the tables statement.

```
tables id*color / noprint sparse out=counts;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `proc sql`, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
proc sql;
    select id,
           sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) as red,
           sum(case when color = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) as blue,
           sum(case when color = 'green' then 1 else 0 end) as green
    from t
    group by id;
```